# How to get longtable to make the rows flushbottom?

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtable

I have a `longtable` where every row can have a slightly different height and is followed by a `\hline`. How can I get the rows of the pages to be `\flushbottom`end?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\flushbottom
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]\newpage
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}
\lipsum[1]\tabularnewline\hline
\lipsum[1]\tabularnewline\hline
\lipsum[1]\tabularnewline\hline
\lipsum[1]\tabularnewline\hline
\lipsum[1]\tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

A pdf is [here](http://www.oneiros.de/privat/texsx/longtableflushbottom.pdf). Ideally every row should stretch, but I'd be satisfied if only the last one was stretched.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Are you asking how to relax the line spacing parameters so that the final line of a given paragraph will be at the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you can't.

What you could do is insert some stretch space *between* rows (so long as you have no vertical rules) for example

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\flushbottom
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]\newpage
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}
\lipsum[1]\tabularnewline\hline\noalign{\vfill}
\lipsum[1]\tabularnewline\hline\noalign{\vfill}
\lipsum[1]\tabularnewline\hline\noalign{\vfill}
\lipsum[1]\tabularnewline\hline\noalign{\vfill}
\lipsum[1]\tabularnewline\hline\noalign{\vfill}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Pushes the rows down turning

[image]

into this:

[image]

But you can't affect the typesetting within the rows for the usual reasons that TeX page breaking happens in the output routine after the galley has been set so can't affect the boxes within the page.

Of course it is possible to do anything, but not necessarily possible with that package...

Comment: Sigh. I feared as much. I'll ask if that feature is really needed (of course one can imagine a multi-pass solution for this, but that's probably too much work). But at least I have another question for the ConTeXt experts. `:-)`.